# "the challenge to do X" vs "the challenge of doing X"

Tags: phrase-choice

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- the challenge **to** do X
- the challenge **of** do**ing** X

Example:

> The models in the literature tend to employ different strategies to encode the input, leading to **the challenge to determine** the best input encoding scheme for this problem.

Comment: Good question, I think both are correct, however, I don't know why I have a feeling that "a challenge" sounds better than "the challenge" I have no idea to support. I would say "leading to a challenge to ...". I am a learner though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically fine. "the challenge to do X" emphasizes X as  unit, a thing to be accomplished. "the challenge of doing X" emphasizes X as a process, perhaps with challenging aspects or steps. But in many contexts the meanings of the two forms will be essentially identical.

The example sentence:

> ...  leading to the challenge to determine the best input encoding scheme ...

could be rewritten as

> leading to the challenge of determining the best input encoding scheme ...

with no significant change in meaning.